# Page-scope variables in Django

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and Python. What I'm trying to achive is so simple in other frameworks that I am familiar with. But I couldn't find an easy/quick way for it in Django on the internet. I wouldn't use templates for this very basic operation if unnecessary.

```
{% for tweet in tweets.itertuples %}

{% if tweet.sent == 'pos' %}
{% with color_class='text-success' %}
{% endwith %}
{% with fa_class='smile' %}
{% endwith %}
{% elif tweet.sent == 'neg' %}
{% with color_class='text-danger' %}
{% endwith %}
{% with fa_class='frown' %}
{% endwith %}
{% else %}
{% with color_class='text-muted' %}
{% endwith %}
{% with fa_class='meh' %}
{% endwith %}
{% endif %}

<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <small class="text-muted">{{ tweet.unix }}</small>
    </div>
    <h2>
      <i class="fa fa-{% if true %} smile {% endif %} text-{% if true %} success {% endif %}"></i>
      <a class="article-title text-{% if tweet.sent == 'pos' %} 'success' {% endif %}" href="#">
        {{ tweet.sentiment }}
      </a>     
    </h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ tweet.tweet }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```

the following part doesn't get rendered as I want.

```
<i class="fa fa-{% if true %} smile {% endif %} text-{% if true %} success {% endif %}"></i>
<a class="article-title text-{% if tweet.sent == 'pos' %} 'success' {% endif %}" href="#">
```

What it renders:

```
<i class="fa fa- text-"></i>
<a class="article-title text-" href="#">-0.6</a>
```

What I want:

```
<i class="fa fa-smile text-success"></i>
<a class="article-title text-success" href="#">
```

Probably what I need at this point is to set page-scope variables. But how?

Answer (score 0):

In views.py:

```
tweets['sent_icon_class'] = tweets['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: ("smile" if x > 0 else "frown" if x < 0 else "meh"))
tweets['sent_color_class'] = tweets['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: ("success" if x > 0 else "danger" if x < 0 else "muted"))
```

In index.html:

```
{% for tweet in tweets.itertuples %}
<article class="media content-section">
  <div class="media-body">
    <div class="article-metadata">
      <small class="text-muted">{{ tweet.created_at }}</small>
    </div>
    <h2>
      <i class="fa fa-{{ tweet.sent_icon_class }} text-{{ tweet.sent_color_class }}"></i>
      <a class="article-title text-{{ tweet.sent_color_class }}" href="#">
        {{ tweet.sentiment }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="article-content">{{ tweet.tweet|safe }}</p>
  </div>
</article>
{% endfor %}
```